# Can I reference a Scenario in another Scenario?

Tags: meteor, meteor-cucumber

I have a user-signup Scenario, and then I want to use that DB state for two different action flows. Currently I'm doing:

```
Scenario
  [copy all the whens from user-signup Scenario]
  When ..
  Then action A is complete

Scenario
  [copy all the whens from user-signup Scenario]
  When ..
  Then action B is complete
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
Background
  Given user-signup Scenario

Scenario
  When ..
  Then action A is complete

Scenario
  When ..
  Then action B is complete
```

Note that I don't want to write a method that sets up the user data, because it's complex and varying based on 3rd party API calls (so I can't just insert json records).

Comment: Exactly this same question came up on my project yesterday. Haven't found an answer yet. Could velocity *helpers* help?

Comment: This looks like it's just for getting elements and methods https://velocity.readme.io/docs/velocity-helpers

Comment: So far I've found velocity to be about an order of magnitude more complicated than Meteor itself :(

Comment: This is my third time trying it, other times couldn't get it to work. This time seems like it works, just could use a lot of documentation.

Comment: It would be interesting to check if the Gherkin syntax itself allows this.

Comment: Not seeing anything: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then    https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You could move things into helper functions, or you could switch to mocha e2e with chimpjs, which is better suited. Ref:

https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/issues/147